# Работа с SOAP по протоколу https

Tags: python, python-2.x, soap

Для работа с SOAP в Python есть библиотека suds. Проблема в том, что мне надо работать по протоколу `https`. В этом лучае `suds` при наборе `Client(url)` ругается на меня следующим образом:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Ничего лучше не придумал, чем посылать xml через requests так:

```
response = requests.post(url,headers = headers, data = xml, verify = False)
```

Так все работает, но хочется все-таки воспользоваться готовыми решениями. Есть ли способ обойти `ssl` в `suds` ?

Comment: Ну, он в общем-то правильно ругается, потому что сертификат там действительно кривой, у него проблемы с путем сертификации.

Comment: А как вы узнали ?

Comment: Ну так в исходной версии вопроса был указан адрес сайта. Если его ввести в браузер, тот тоже обругается на сертификат.

Comment: заголовок и тело вопроса не соответствуют друг другу. 1- выясните правильный ли сертификат ([добавьте CA, если необходимо](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12865159/4279)) 2- если сертификат неправильный, например, просрочен, тогда имеет смысл вопрос ["как *выключить* ssl в suds"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27835619/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Bypass SSL when I'm using SUDS for consume web service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37327368/4279)